# .NET Signalr MapConnection is Obsolete?

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

I am new to .Net and SignalR.  I am looking at some code written by a former coworker and he added this line to the Route Config which is now throwing errors saying its obsolete but all the [documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections) I have read suggest mapping connections in this way.

```
namespace FailureInvestigationToolbox {
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes( RouteCollection routes ) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name :"Default",
            url :"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults :new {
                controller = "fit",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<TaskListPersistence>("taskpersist", "/taskpersist");
    }
}
}
```

The error is:

```
System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapConnection<T>    
(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection, string, string)' is obsolete: 
'Use IAppBuilder.MapSignalR<TConnection> in an Owin Startup class. See
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320578 for more details.'  
C:\fit\FailureInvestigationToolbox\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs
```

Is it possible I have something wrong with my SignalR installation or is the IAppBuilder way of mapping things what I'm supposed to do...if so how?

I am using SignalR 2.0.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `IAppBuilder`. Add a Owin `Startup` class, and in its `Configuration` method call `MapConnection<T>` on the `app` argument you receive. That should work. Check [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) and [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#route).

Comment: And maybe check [this here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20) (**upgrading SignalR1x to 2.0**) as well.

Answer (score 28):

You can use this [article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20) ,

1.In the global application class, remove the call to MapHubs.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

2.Right-click the solution, and select Add, New Item.... In the dialog, select Owin Startup Class. Name the new class Startup.cs.

3.Replace the contents of Startup.cs with the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a review on my this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911209/what-is-the-right-way-to-implement-signalr-in-asp-net-webform-project question

Answer (score 3):

To enable SignalR in your application, create a class called Startup with the following:

using Owin;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}