# Unable to resolve System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection)' is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to implement SignalR in my MVC application but I am getting the following error:
I am getting the following error:

```
System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection)' 
is obsolete: 'Use IAppBuilder.MapSignalR in an Owin Startup class. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320578 
for more details.
```

After searching for solution online I stumbled upon  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635398/net-signalr-mapconnection-is-obsolete/28424734)

So I added the Startup file and now my code now looks like :

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyTestMVCApp.Startup))]

namespace MyTestMVCApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
             app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax:**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();//error here                
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();    
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
```

I am still getting the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: The `MapSignalR` call should do the routing for the hubs registered in the container. No need for `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs`. To register the hubs in the container you can call `AddSignalR` on the `IServiceCollection`.

Comment: @Dr.Fre can you please post it as an answer? Along with the corrected code. I am not sure what you meant by `To register the hubs in the container you can call AddSignalR on the IServiceCollection.` . I am a total newbie here as far as signalR is concerned.